# running playwright on bitbucket pipeline but doesn't generate html report and upload it to s3 server

Tags: amazon-s3, bitbucket, report, pipeline, playwright

I'm trying to upload playwright html report with error only(probably without too) to s3 server using bitbucket pipeline.

I've searched for google and youtube, I can't find any solutions.

```
image: qawolf/playwright-ci:v1.0.0
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Playwright Tests
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm init playwright@latest 
          - npx playwright install
          - cd tests
          - cd staging
          - npx playwright test --reporter=html
          - cd ..
          - cd ..
          - cd playwright-report
          - mkdir "$(date +"%d-%m-%Y %I %M %p")"
          - mv index.html "$(date +"%d-%m-%Y %I %M %p")"
        artifacts:
          - playwright-report/*
    - step:
        name: Deploy to S3
        deployment: staging
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/aws-s3-deploy:0.3.8
            variables:
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: 'CLASSIFIED'
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 'CLASSIFIED'
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 'CLASSIFIED'
              S3_BUCKET: 'CLASSIFIED'
              LOCAL_PATH: 'playwright-report'
              ACL: 'public-read'
```

Comment: Have you confirmed you have saved the report in the artifacts?

Comment: I have confirmed, using ls

Comment: Not with `ls` but that they are in the artifacts tab for the pipeline step

Comment: I have checked it, there's nothing to artifacts

Comment: Well then you can't upload it if you don't save it properly. Figure out where it get's saved and correct the artifact path